# Passing control to controller through href in jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a link `Reset User` in my jsp page; on clicking of this it should perform some backend operatons (resetting the password). I am trying to pass the control to my controller through href.

The following is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Admin/ResetSupplierPassword">Reset Password
```

However it's not going to the controller's method (I guess I'm missing something) as instead it's opening a new page which doesn't exist (that's what href supposed to do). The `reset link` is not inside any form tag. If it's in inside any form tag I guess could use an ajax call.

Is there any *other* way to pass control other then href and ajax?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you should use

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ResetSupplierPassword">Reset password</a>
```

only.You dont have to put **Admin** package name. I guess if you would mention the servlet entry correctly in web.xml then you wont even have to bother about the path of the servlet. You can simple use:

```
<a href="ResetSupplierPassword">Reset password</a>
```

Apart from that i think assigning form action="ResetSupplierPassword" attr or Ajax are the only methods that are good to be used.